# Detect touch down & touch up in a view containing UIControls

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, touches, touch-event

I'm trying to detect when a user touches down and up in a view. The view contains some buttons and other UIKit controls. I would like to detect these touch events but not consume them.

I've tried two approaches, but neither has been sufficient:

First I added a transparent overlay overriding -touchesBegan:withEvent: and -touchesEnded:withEvent: and forward the event to the next responder with

```
[self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]
```

However, it seems that UIKit objects ignore all forwarded events.

Next, I tried overriding -pointInside:withEvent: and -hitTest:withEvent: . This worked great to detect touch *down* events, but pointInside:: and hitTest:: are not called on touch *up* (i.e. [[[event allTouches] anyObject] phase] is never equal to UITouchPhaseEnded ).

What's the best way to detect both touch down and touch up events without disturbing interaction with the underlying UIControls?

Comment: I see no reason why a responder would ignore `touchesBegan:withEvent:` just because it'd been sent to something else with the same event already. That defies the point of the responder chain. Are you sure `nextResponder` is returning something?

Comment: @Peter "The classes of the UIKit framework are not designed to receive touches that are not bound to them; in programmatic terms, this means that the view property of the UITouch object must hold a reference to the framework object in order for the touch to be handled. If you want to conditionally forward touches to other responders in your application, all of these responders should be instances of your own subclasses of UIView." (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the [Event Handling Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH3-SW17)
you have 3 options:

1) subclassing UIWindow to override sendEvent:

2) using an overlay view

3) designing so that you don't have to do that... so really more like 2 options.

Here is a simplification of apples example, using UIWindow subclass;

1) change the class of your window in the NIB to your subclass of UIWindow.
2) put this method in the .m file.

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSSet * allTouches = [event allTouches];

    NSMutableSet *began = nil;
    NSMutableSet *moved = nil;
    NSMutableSet *ended = nil;
    NSMutableSet *cancelled = nil;

    // sort the touches by phase so we can handle them similarly to normal event dispatch
    for(UITouch *touch in allTouches) {
        switch ([touch phase]) {
            case UITouchPhaseBegan:
                if (!began) began = [NSMutableSet set];
                [began addObject:touch];
                break;
            case UITouchPhaseMoved:
                if (!moved) moved = [NSMutableSet set];
                [moved addObject:touch];
                break;
            case UITouchPhaseEnded:
                if (!ended) ended = [NSMutableSet set];
                [ended addObject:touch];
                break;
            case UITouchPhaseCancelled:
                if (!cancelled) cancelled = [NSMutableSet set];
                [cancelled addObject:touch];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        // call our methods to handle the touches
        if (began)
        {
            NSLog(@"the following touches began: %@", began);
        };
        if (moved)
        {
            NSLog(@"the following touches were moved: %@", moved);
        };
        if (ended)
        {
             NSLog(@"the following touches were ended: %@", ended);
        };
        if (cancelled) 
        {
             NSLog(@"the following touches were cancelled: %@", cancelled);
        };
    }
    [super sendEvent:event];
}
```

It has way too much output, but you will get the idea... and can make your logic fit where you want it to.

Comment: If I detect touches in an overlay, calling [super touchesBegan:] does not forward the event to the views underneath. And if I detect touches in a parent view, a child UIButton consumes the touches and my touchesBegan: is never called.

Comment: you were right about that, the UIView was swallowing the events, I modified apples example of a UIWindow subclass.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that approach. (I don't know why you're being downvoted.)